# bootstrap css styles not working after upgrading angular 4 to angular 5

Tags: css, angular

Created SPA application using Angular 4, .net core 2. Used bootstrap for styling.

After successfully upgrade from angular 4 to angular 5 all the bootstrap styling is gone. 
Looks like the bootstrap.css is not being loaded.

Comment: Are you using the angular-cli and how do you reference the css file?

Comment: I am new to angular. I have made angular project using .net core 2.

Comment: Okay but you should provide some code, like where ur css is loaded and how does your index.html look like

Comment: i added bootstrap to package.json.

Comment: and it was working fine like this in angular4 but after upgrade to angular5 it is not working.

Comment: this what i have in package.json for bootstrap ("bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",)

Comment: You added bootstrap to package.json? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have added bootstrap 4 to package.json per your comment:

> this what i have in package.json for bootstrap ("bootstrap":
>   "^4.0.0-beta.3",)

Did you have an earlier version (Bootstrap 3 or even Bootstrap 4 beta 2)? There are major changes from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4, and even from Bootstrap 4 beta versions. Check Bootstrap migration doc: [Migrating to v4 - Bootstrap][1]

If you want to continue using Bootstrap 3, you can use these links:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Sorry, my [Migrating to v4 - Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) link wasn't appearing as expected. Here is the link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RusselD. Indeed that was the issue some of the classes from bootstrap 3 which I was using are now not in bootstrap 4. After changing them to proper it is working again.
Thank you all for the quick replies. Appreciated